# How to make this select box and button stay next to each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like this select box and button to be next to each other and centered in the middle, with let's say 20px space between them, and I am trying to use Bootstrap in order to make it responsive so the two items stack under each other when the window is resized. Any ideas how to improve this..?

Updated code: codepen.io/anon/pen/gLJYPj

Any ideas how to make select and button stack under each other and stay centered?

Non-Bootstrap solution would also be great!

```
<div class="container search">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="search__region">
          <select>
            <option value="">Select something</option>
            <option value="">One</option>
            <option value="">Two</option>
            <option value="">Three</option>
          </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="search__button">
            <button class="search__region--button">button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end search container -->

.search {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 215px;
}

.search__region {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.search__region select {
  padding: 10px 18px;
  height: 55px;
  width: 130%;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.search__region--button {
  padding: 16px 0px;
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: adding clasess `<div class="search__region pull-right">` and `<div class="search__button pull-left">` helps?

Comment: unfortunately not because it becomes a mess when resized, and it's not centered. non-bootstrap solution would also be great, it does not have utilize its grid, that's just a way I tried to do it

Comment: gave you my answer..

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**Bootstrap Input Groups**](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons) and keep the button and the select element together.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="input-group">

  <select class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select something</option>
    <option value="">One</option>
    <option value="">Two</option>
    <option value="">Three</option>
  </select>

  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Button</button>
  </span> 
</div>
```

If you want to still have your wrapping div's `.search__region` and `search__button` that can be added too without breaking the UI.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="search__region">
    <select class="form-control">
      <option value="">Select something</option>
      <option value="">One</option>
      <option value="">Two</option>
      <option value="">Three</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="search__button input-group-btn">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Button</button>
  </span> 
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, both answers were very useful, I managed to get the look that I need, now I only need to stack the select and button under each other so it's centered when it's resized(any ideas or an existing Bootstrap class perhaps?), here' s the updated code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLJYPj

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using input-group like this works. http://codepen.io/lhrossi/pen/mOgNgp

```
<div class="input-group">
      <span class="search__region">
          <select>
            <option value="">Select something</option>
            <option value="">One</option>
            <option value="">Two</option>
            <option value="">Three</option>
          </select>
        </span>
            <button class="search__region--button">button</button>
    </div>
```

Just need some minor css fixes.